# Next steps in learning computer design

Tags: digital-logic

I know book recommendations are off-topic here. (Any book you can recommend will soon be out of date.) Rather than asking for *a book*, I'm asking for how to locate and evaluate potential books.

Last year I read several books with titles like "introduction to digital logic" and similar. As I expected, I already knew *most* of the material, although I did learn a few interesting new things. Now I'd like to take the next step... but I'm not sure exactly what that is.

All the books I read talked about basic logic gates, De Morgan duality, K-maps, combinatorial logic vs sequential logic, the different types of latches and flip-flops (in varying levels of detail). Most of the books get as far as describing multiplexers, decoders and a simple ripple adder.

However, none of the books seem to go any further than that. For example, nowhere is there a diagram for how to do multiplication in hardware. Certainly none of them describe how an entire processor might be constructed. Now *I think* I know how to do this — but I'd prefer to read something written by actual experts on the subject.

So what I'm looking for is a book that describes how to design all the major components of a computer system at the gate level. I know nobody *does* this anymore (unless you work for one of the 3 companies on Earth who still design microprocessors), but I'd like to learn anyway.

If anybody can suggest what search terms I might use and what to look for in a table of contents, that would be great. I imagine if I search "computer design" it will just be books that tell you what ICs to purchase and how to connect them. I don't want that; I want gate-level design principles.

Comment: If you think you know how it works, you probably do. The step from logic gates etc to a simple processor is not that hard, because simple processors are ridiculously simple. Maybe read up about the Z80? It is simple, yet introduces all the main concepts that are still valid today, and there is a huge amount of documentation on it.

Comment: *"I know nobody does this anymore"* As designing a small processor is FUN you would be amazed about how many small processors you can find in the various ASICs because some senior designers persuaded their management that it was necessary to have this 'dedicated functionality'. (often in the Clock Reset And  Powermanagement area)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of abstract teaching books. Perhaps the most famous being [Hennessey and Patterson's "Computer Architecture"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128119055) [Patterson and Hennessey's Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface] and ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/0123747503](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123747503)). The first is more for hardware design folks. The second is more for software types, who want a little hardware with their software. (The second one also comes with specialized versions for MIPS, ARM, and RISC-V.)

But those above are much more designed for a classroom setting where there are advisors, lectures, and other students to co-ordinate with, as well as exercises and lab work to do.

---

For a book that includes a multiplier design, you might consider [Douglas Smith's "Hdl Chip Design: A Practical Guide for Designing, Synthesizing & Simulating Asics & Fpgas Using Vhdl or Verilog"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0965193438). It includes dividers, as well. And many other interesting functions.

It's an early book by a British author who moved to the US around the time of writing the book. (I spoke with him soon after his arrival in the US.) The book does something unique: It is written in "parallels" where on one side there is the function performed in Verilog and on the other side there is the same function performed in "VHDL." And the book doesn't only present one way to do things. It also elaborates on the trade-offs. Finally, this book is definitely designed for the absolute beginner. So it's pretty easy to read.

---

Ben Eater has [a bunch of web pages and videos](https://eater.net/8bit) to help you actually build something using 7400 series parts (and a few other electronic parts, of course) that will handle 8-bit data and instructions. You might look up those. They are somewhat scattered, in a way. But they aren't terribly hard to understand and, I think, people here would be helpful with specific questions as you proceeded through them. So this might be one approach to take a look at and see if it fits your interests well enough.

---

There is [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/) (which is, now, a long-retired software product) that performs logic simulations and includes a lot of useful "parts" you can apply. You should be able to find some completed MCUs using Logisim on the web. Having something concrete like that, which you can simulate, goes a long way towards learning.

I don't use Logisim for anything now, because there is something *much better*. This is [Neemann's DIGITAL](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital) product. This is actively maintained and actually includes several different MCU implementations in its installation. So you don't even have to go looking around.

---

For a complete, step by step, design of the Z80 processor you could do no better than [Monte Darlymple's "Microprocessor Design Using Verilog HDL"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0963013351). This is a very, very serious and very, very detailed step-by-step process that goes all the way from ground zero to a final result. It's very good.

---

If you are just interested in a beginner's overview (and by this I mean that the book goes into enough interesting detail without going all the way to completion), then I think perhaps the easiest book of all to read on the topic is [Clive Maxfield's "Bebop Bytes Back: An Unconventional Guide to Computers"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0965193403).

---

For just fun, also have a look at [Harry Porter's Relay Computer](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/).

Answer (score 1):

Look for textbooks that major universities use for computer arithmetic and introductory computer architecture courses.  Look for Computer Science textbooks that cover arithmetic and Universal Turing machines.  Look for textbooks on the history of computer architecture and computer design.  Old (1989 or earlier) used textbooks might possibly cover more of the low level logic.

There are also open source low gate count processors designed for embedding in older FPGAs.  Perhaps study those.

At the bottom, it's all just state machines, logic units, and memory arrays.